# how to replicate zoom out effect by scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, web

How can I replicate the effect used on Apple's 5k iMac website where scrolling down gives the effect of zooming out? Here is the site:

http://www.apple.com/imac-with-retina/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it for most browsers:

```js
window.onmousewheel= function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if((e.wheelDelta || -e.detail) < 1) {
    document.body.style.zoom--;
  }
  else {
    document.body.style.zoom++;
  }
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```